# Angular date filter not triggerd when ng-model has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with AngularJS which I cannot seem te fix, since I don't know what I am doing wrong.

---

**Versions**

AngularJS: 1.6.1

Angular-material: 1.1.1

---

**Problem**

I am building a datetimepicker using AngularJS components and filters. 
When I click on the shown date (formatted via `{{ $ctrl.model | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' }}u`) an Angular-material popup with a custom datetimepicker opens and shows some options to change the date. After the user clicks on 'confirm' the date is passed to my component (the one that opens the dialog) and assigns the new date to the model `this.model =  newDate.getMomentDate();`. After this I would expect that the view date would also be updated and formatted. Yet it is only updated and not formatted.

**Expected result:** 28-02-2016 00:00u

**Result:** Sun Feb 28 2016 00:00:57 GMT+0100u

---

**Used components**

To make this functionality I used a few angular components:

- A component in my app's code (time.component.ts)
- A HTMl file that displays stuff (time.html)
- A component that transcludes the time (`{{ $ctrl.model | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' }}u`) into the time.html and manages the dialog (datetimepicker.ts)
- A HTML file with the model - transcluded into the time.html (datetimepicker.html)
- A controller that manages the dialog (datetimepickerdialog.controller.ts)
- A html file with the dialog (datetimedialog.html)
- A model that holds the information of the dialog (DateTimePickerModel.ts)

[image: A model that describes the connections between the classes]

---

**time.html**

```
<date-time-picker title="pick your time"
                  model="$ctrl.time.meeting">
</date-time-picker>
```

**datetimepicker.component.ts**

*bindings*

```
bindings: {
    model: "=",  //Angular ng-model is automatically updated this way
    title: "@?"
},
transclude: true,
controller: DateTimePickerController
```

*Picker callback*

```
showPicker(): void {
     this.$mdDialog.show(this.datePickerDialog).then((newDate: DateTimePickerModel) => {
         this.model =  newDate.getMomentDate();
     }, function () {
         //Cancel
      });
}
```

**datepicker.html**

```
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showPicker()" aria-label="open dialog">
    {{ $ctrl.model | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' }}u
</md-button>
```

**DateTimePickerModel.ts**

```
export class DateTimePickerModel {
    constructor(public day: string,
                public month: string,
                public year: string,
                public hour: string,
                public minute: string,
                public second: string) {
        }

     /**
      * Returns the number of days of the month
      * @return number
      */
      getDaysInMonth(): number {
         return moment(this.year + '-' + this.month).daysInMonth();
      }

     /**
      * Formats the property values to a moment date
      * @return {Moment}
      */
     getMomentDate(): Moment {
        return moment(
            this.year + "-" + this.month + "-" + this.day + "T" +
            this.hour + ":" + this.minute + ":" + this.second,
            moment.ISO_8601);
      }
}
```

I left out the datetimepickerdialog.controller.ts, because an instance of the DateTimePickerModel is passed to the controller and it has nothing to do with the 2-way-binding or the ng-model (I am not expecting that there is anything in that controller that can cause the problem).

---

**I Tried**

I Tried using `$scope.$apply()` bercause I expected that Angular did not see the change. But using the `$scope.$apply()` I get the error `'Digest is already running'`.

I also tried replacing the 2-way-binding of the component (`"="`) with the one-way-binding (`"<"`) and returning the date into the time.component.ts with a function. In the `time.component.ts` I would then update the `ng-model` with the new date. Yet this gives me the same result.

I found a workarround that works, but that goes against the whole purpose of Angular filters. For this I am manipulating the model inside my controller via a get method. This also works and updates when changes are found. But I pollutes my controller with view manipulation. (I DO NOT ADVICE THIS!)

**datetimepicker.component.ts**

```
/**
 * Formats the model and return the formatted version.
 * - An Angular filter didn't work. It was somehow only called once, if the model changed it didn't format it -
 * @return {string}
 */
get formattedModel(): string {
    return moment(this.model).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
}
```

**datetimepicker.html**

```
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showPicker()" aria-label="open dialog">
    {{ $ctrl.formattedModel }}u
</md-button>
```

I cannot think of any other options, because Angular runs every filter on the page on every `$digest` cycle, because it doesn't know on what filters the ng-model has effect. (every change could have effect on the page so it needs te reevaluate every filter, every cycle).

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: While so many people fail to provide enough to detail to get the help they need you've gone to the other extreme.  You've provided so much info that I don't have the time to read or consume all of it.  Create a plunker and link to it.

Comment: I Agree with you that I should use a plunker. But the problem is that I am using TypeScript and that cannot be run. I would need to use the javascript, but that is compiled and quite unreadable. Any suggestion on how I should create a plunker of it?

Comment: Plunker supports 1.5x + TS

Answer (score 0):

This is very general because your question is quite detailed.

First of all, Angular 1.6 is not compatible with Material 1.1.1 just yet, so I would start with trying all this with Angular 1.5 and seeing if this doesn't address your problem. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10111

Second of all, if you are making a component that uses model, consider following the pattern of actually using ng-model directly, as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Third of all, why not isolate the specific problem with testing, then you'll know if it's something in the component or something with how you're using the modal. For example, replace your time picker component with the material date time picker. If that works then you know the problem is in your component and has nothing to do with the modal.

Comment: 1) I removed Angular-material from the component (used simple html tags instead) got the same error, so thats not it.

2) I agree with you on the ng-model thing, but that means we have to refactor a whole lot (big application and never knew about the pattern). Something to take into account in the future. 

3) My code is very differend to the Angular-material components so unfortunately I cannot simply replace it and use the same bindings and stuff.